# What are the other metrics that we can use in Sequential Pattern Mining, when using SPADE algorithm?

Tags: r, sequential-pattern-mining

I'm reading this awesome page with interest metrics used in Association Rules:
https://michael.hahsler.net/research/association_rules/measures.html

As I have sequential data, I decided to use the [arulesSequences](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arulesSequences/arulesSequences.pdf) from R, which
do Sequential Pattern Mining, and create the rules using the SPADE algorithm.
Here are some rules created:

```
head(as(rules, 'data.frame'))
           rule                              support         confidence         lift
1    <{A}> => <{B}>                        0.026485890       0.13160987      0.8112745
2    <{D}> => <{B}>                        0.009853382       0.03726893      0.2297345
3     <{C}> => <{B}>                       0.063455778       0.10779325      0.6644632
4   <{C},{A}> => <{B}>                     0.018524358       0.24607330      1.5168542
6    <{D}> => <{E}>                        0.015607757       0.14494876      3.1703792
7    <{A}> => <{F}>                        0.011587577       0.05757932      1.2593987
```

I'm thinking if makes sense to calculate some other metrics, like [Chi Squared](https://michael.hahsler.net/research/association_rules/measures.html#chisquared) test (to test the null hypothesis that Lift = 0 for a specific rule), or calculate the [Standardized Lift](https://michael.hahsler.net/research/association_rules/measures.html#stdLift).
And if makes sense, there's some function in this package or in another to calculate these new metrics?
I have my doubts because the `cspade()` function only creates rules with `support`, `confidence` and `lift`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This book](https://www-users.cs.umn.edu/%7Ekumar001/dmbook/index.php) is one of the most useful resources I've found for pattern mining. Chapter 5 (available as a sample chapter) talks about a few properties of interest measures, such as whether the measure is invariant to inversion, scaling, and null addition. When choosing an interest measure it's worth thinking about what conditions are most important.

I'm not overly familiar with R, but the [interestMeasure](https://rdrr.io/cran/arules/man/interestMeasure.html) package looks like what you want. Otherwise the networkx package in Python contains some additional interest measures, or implementing them yourself shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: This book is really awesome, because details a lot of different measures. I think for my case I habe to use assimetric measures, because the order matters. The interestMeasure function is what I needed, but seems that only work for rules, not sequential rules.

Comment: I've used conviction and certainty factor before as asymmetric measures; both have worked well for me, and reduce some of the problems seen with confidence. Calculating them for static rules is very straightforward, they're just based off the item support and the rule support. Rule support should translate directly for sequential rules, but I'm not sure about item support in the sequential case, sorry

Comment: Having our discussion, I found this nice paper, which categorizes measures by assimetric/simetric properties etc. I found very useful: https://www.cse.msu.edu/~ptan/papers/IS.pdf

Comment: After studying the measure's properties, I decided to use `confidence`, because `confidence` is assimetric and null-invariant. If I'm not wrong, this means that 1. $conf(A \rightarrow B) \ne conf(B \rightarrow A)$ (assimetric property) and 2. $conf(A \rightarrow B)$ will not be affected by $supp(\overline{A}, \overline{B})$, where $\overline{}$ means complementary (null-invariant property).  These two measures properties matchs with my business design. By the way, thank you very much @Elenchus, because your recommended book opened my eyes to study assimetric measures!